# Debugging program that sums first 10 values on a file and the next 10 values after

Tags: java, eclipse, file, sum

I am coding a program that is supposed to sum the first 10 values on a file and the second 10 values on a file. The second 10 values are a duplicate of the first 10, so the answers should be the same. My program checks to make sure that the file has been found and halts execution if it has not been found. This is the code I have:

```
package experiment8;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Bugs
{
  public static Scanner inData;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    int fileFound;
    try
    {
      inData = new Scanner(new FileReader("Bugs.dat"));
      fileFound = 1;
    }
    catch (IOException exception)
    {
       fileFound = 2;  
    }
    int  value;
    switch (fileFound)
    {

      case 1 :     
             // do loop
             int  counter = 1;
             int  sum = 0;
             do
             {
               value = inData.nextInt();
               sum = sum + value;
             } while (counter <= 10);
             System.out.println(sum);
             // for loop
             sum = 0;
             for (counter = 1; counter <= 10; counter++)
             {
               value = inData.nextInt();
               sum = sum + value;
               counter++;
             }
            System.out.println(sum);
      case 2 : System.out.println("Bugs.dat not found");
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the content of the file (called "Bugs") the program is supposed to be looking at:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

When I run the program, it outputs the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at lab8.Bugs.main(Bugs.java:31)
```

Comment: Crashes how ? Write exception.

Comment: java.util.NoSuchElementException

Comment: you need to post complete stacktrace as part of your post.

Comment: do
             {
               value = inData.nextInt();
               sum = sum + value;
             } while (counter <= 10);  This is endless loop. Where are you incrementing the counter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `do-while` loop doesn't seem to increment your counter. Also, I'm not sure why you're adding a `counter++` in your `for` loop, its already set in the for loop declaration itself.

Add the `counter++` in your `do-while` loop and remove it from inside the `for` loop.